# Monday 2 weeks from sunday last week. How?

Tags: php, datetime

I run into a bit of a challenge trying to figure out how to capture the range of 2 week payrolls.

How would I go about modifying the `-2W` case?

```
$from = null;
$to = null;

switch ($range) {
  case '1D':
    // code...
    $from = date('Y-m-d ', strtotime('today')) . '00:00:00';
    $to = date('Y-m-d ', strtotime('today')) . '23:59:59';
    $objectView->historyFrom = date('D, F j');
    $objectView->historyTo = date('D, F j');
    break;
  case '1W':
    // code...
    $from = date('Y-m-d ', strtotime('monday this week')) . '00:00:00';
    $to = date('Y-m-d ', strtotime('sunday this week')) . '23:59:59';
    $objectView->historyFrom = date('D, F j', strtotime('monday this week'));
    $objectView->historyTo = date('D, F j', strtotime('sunday this week'));
    break;
  case '-1W':
    // code...
    $from = date('Y-m-d ', strtotime('monday last week')) . '00:00:00';
    $to = date('Y-m-d ', strtotime('sunday last week')) . '23:59:59';
    $objectView->historyFrom = date('D, F j', strtotime('monday last week'));
    $objectView->historyTo = date('D, F j', strtotime('sunday last week'));
    break; 
  case '-2W':
    // code...
    $from = date('Y-m-d ', strtotime('monday previous to last week')) . '00:00:00';
    $to = date('Y-m-d ', strtotime('sunday last week')) . '23:59:59';
    $objectView->historyFrom = date('D, F j', strtotime('monday last week'));
    $objectView->historyTo = date('D, F j', strtotime('sunday last week'));
    break; 
  default:
    // code...
    $from = date('Y-m-d ', strtotime('today')) . '00:00:00';
    $to = date('Y-m-d ', strtotime('today')) . '23:59:59';
    $objectView->historyFrom = date('D, F j');
    $objectView->historyTo = date('D, F j');
    break;
}
```

Comment: So `August 30` or `September 6` for today?

Comment: Precisely yes..!

Comment: No!  Which one?  There was an OR between them.

Comment: August 30 is the correct one.

Comment: Wow. This could be reduced to just a few lines of code if you would use PHP's best tools for working with dates (see DateTime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really look at [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) probably [DatePeriod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php).  But to answer the question with existing code I think you will need two formats, one if today is a Monday and another if it's not:

```
if(date('w') == '1') {
    $from = date('Y-m-d ', strtotime('-2 weeks');
    //or '-14 days'
} else {
    $from = date('Y-m-d ', strtotime('previous monday -2 weeks'));
    //or 'previous monday -14 days'
}
```

Someone may be able to find one format that works for both.

Comment: Like this one liner? `$datetime_from = (new DateTime($thestime))->sub(DateInterval::createFromDateString('45 minutes'))->format('Y-m-d H:i')`

Comment: Something like that but I haven't used the interval much or in a while.